# Grease pencil is showing through objects when I turn on volumetrics

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, grease-pencil, volumetrics

This is with volumetrics on, you can see little pixels of the grease pencil bleeding through objects in the foreground.

[image: volumetrics on]

This is with volumetrics off, here you can see the grease pencil is displaying correctly without the bleeding.

[image]

What is causing this? I want to keep my volumetrics on.