# Grease pencil bleeds through objects when volumetric is on in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, grease-pencil, volumetrics

When grease pencil is used in a scene where volumetrics is on, some pixels of it bleed through the objects in front of it after the image has been rendered using cycles (even when Z pass is on) as mentioned in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/283748/158282). Does anyone know a way to fix it without turning volumetrics off?